# Profile sorting links are broken on meta?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, sorting

So I popped into my profile this morning to check why certain numbers were changing. I did find that out... but in the process, I noticed something funny. My questions were apparently raised to votes power. Unsure where that came from, I saw "votes" was no longer a sort option, so I decided to change to Newest to see if this was just an in-progress marker for the current sort. It didn't take.

I have a limitted test assortment here, but it occurs on IE8 but not the latest FireFox. I did fix my sort by popping into FF on another machine. A check on [Welbog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog-vas-stack-overflow), the topmost user in the questions list to a not-logged-in-user-at-the-time, showed that the problem in IE8 was present on that computer as well. This only happens on meta, does not appear to occur in the other 3 sites.

[image: How did it even get there?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, I made a typo and there was an extra `"`. Only IE8 seemed to care.

Comment: Yay! Thanks Jeff! Quite a quick fix there.

Comment: Stupid IE 8 not liking your code. Why can't it be smart like Chrome?